# On simultaneous embeddings with different vertex sets

Tags: planar-graphs, graph-drawing

The topic of simultaneous embeddings of planar graphs is a common sight in the recent graph drawing literature. A recent survey of the topic is given by [Bläsius, Kobourov and Ritter](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5853). I am interested in the case of Simultaneous Embeddings with Fixed Edges (SEFE), which is the following problem:

**Input:** Two graphs $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$, sharing a common subgraph $G=(V=V_1 \cap V_2, E=E_1 \cap E_2)$.

**Problem:** Do there exist planar embeddings of $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that the vertices and the edges of $G$ are mapped to the same vertices and Jordan arcs in both embeddings (i.e., do there exist two embeddings which agree on $G$).

The complexity of SEFE is an open problem.

According to the aforementioned survey, this problem can be solved in linear time when the intersection graph $G$ is a star, as it can be reduced to a variant of $2$-page embedding, for which an algorithm is known. However, looking at the [corresponding paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866711001183), the input is slightly different: the vertex sets of $G_1$ and $G_2$ are assumed to be the same. Without this assumption, neither the reduction nor the [corresponding algorithm](http://www-or.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/nag/Technical_report/TR2009-004.pdf) seem to adapt (at least the definition of splitters should be modified).

Hence my questions:

- Maybe I am missing something obvious: In general for the SEFE problem, is there an easy way to reduce the case of $V_1 \neq V_2$ to the equal vertex set case? (obviously one can just add copies of the exclusive vertices of $V_1$ to $V_2$ and vice versa, but this changes a lot the structure and the connectivity of the intersection graph, which is critical for most algorithms)
- If not, is a polynomial-time algorithm known to solve the SEFE problem when the intersection graph is a star but the vertex sets are different?

Comment: Just a note: in Gassner et al., "Simultaneous Graph Embeddings with Fixed Edges"  (in which they prove that the decision problem is NP-complete when there are three or more input graphs) the SEFE problem is defined on a set of graphs that *share* the same vertex set $V$.